# Imagemagick combine several commands

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have four images, a.png, b.png, c.png, d.png.
Now I would like to compose image a, b and c and colorize them after that I would like to compose the result with d.png. I want to do this with one command:

`magick a.png b.png c.png -compose -channel R -evaluate multiply 0.9 -channel G -evaluate multiply 0.9 -channel B -evaluate multiply 0.9 d.png -compose result.png`

But this does not work for me to get the right output I have to made this by two steps:

`magick a.png b.png c.png -channel R -evaluate multiply 0.9 -channel G -evaluate multiply 0.9 -channel B -evaluate multiply 0.9 step.png`

and

`magick step.png d.png -compose result.png`

Is there any solution to combine several commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you are trying to do, but hopefully the following thoughts will help...

Firstly, you have

```
... -channel R -evaluate multiply 0.9 -channel G -evaluate multiply 0.9 -channel B -evaluate multiply 0.9
```

when you might as well use:

```
... channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9
```

Secondly, after selecting a specific channel to work on (with `-channel`), you should then revert back to dealing with all channels (using `+channel`) before your final `-composite`. So, I think you may do better with this:

```
magick a.png b.png c.png -composite -channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9 +channel d.png -composite result.png
```

Comment: I will try this, but I have different values for RGB so I have to use -channel R, -channel G ... I hope that it works

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve that is by combining multiple images (as layers): http://cloudinary.com/blog/transform_your_image_overlays_with_on_the_fly_manipulation where each layer can be manipulated, e.g. colorized: http://cloudinary.com/cookbook/color_a_picture

The URL that does all this is equivalent in complexity to a one-line magick command, with tons of added benefit such as optimized delivery. You can do it with a demo account or just grab your own free Cloudinary account.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's a good alternative but not the answer of my question, I have to use imagemagick. But Thx