# Imagemagick convert several commands

Tags: image, imagemagick

after I received an answer: [Imagemagick combine several commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157679/imagemagick-combine-serveral-commands)
 - a new question arose. I have image a, b, c, d and e
and I want to colorize and compose them in a specific order 
Like that:

`a.png b.png -composite -gravity center -channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9 step1.png`

`c.png d.png -composite -gravity center -channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9 step2.png`

`step1.png step2.png e.png -composite -gravity center result.png`

but in one command like that

`((a.png b.png -composite -gravity center -channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9) (c.png d.png -composite -gravity center -channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9) -composite -gravity center) e.png -composite -gravity center result.png`

but with brackets it doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Now I found my mistake, I have to use spaces like this:

`( ( a.png b.png -composite -gravity center -channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9 ) ( c.png d.png -composite -gravity center -channel RGB -evaluate multiply 0.9 ) -composite -gravity center ) e.png -composite -gravity center result.png`